# Extraction of elements of tuples

Tags: list, tuples, erlang

Given one list with one tuple:

```
[{4,1,144}]
```

How to extract the first element of the tuple inside the list:

```
element(1,lists:nth(1,L))
```

Do you have a simpler solution?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this:

```
1> A = [{3,1,1444}].
[{3,1,1444}]
2> [{X, _, _}] = A.
[{3,1,1444}]
3> X.
3
4>
```

Comment: I like this solution very simple ;-)

Comment: What if the tuple is of arbitrary length? How can I write a function to do this?

Comment: First of all: You should not have tuples of _arbitrary length_. In those scenarios you should use lists. But… if you insist: `AListOfTuples = generate:your_list_of_tuples(), [FirstTuple|_] = AListOfTuples, [X|_] = tuple_to_list(FirstTuple), X.`

Answer (score 32):

Given that you get exactly what you state, a list with one tuple, even easier would be (using [element/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#element-2))

```
element(1, hd(L)).
```

A pattern matching variant like shk suggested is probably even nicer, depending on the context.

Answer (score 5):

you could also consider using records syntax if you want some semantics embedded into your tuples

```
-record(x, {y, z}).

1> A = #x{y=b, z=c}.
2> A#x.y.
b
```

all records are in fact tuples and you dont have to worry about order of elements in that tuple nor about adding/removing elements.