# Split the tuple in erlang

Tags: erlang

I want to split this tuple into:

```
 {d,[{{1,c},{2,g}},{{3,f},{4,f}}]}

  a = [1,c],[2,g]  
  b = [3,f],[4,f]
```

where a and b are just variable

I tried looking at [extraction of elements of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819506/extraction-of-elements-of-tuples)

But not able to split it like that I want.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming first element of the tuple doesn't matter, and the second is always a two-element list:

```
{_, [A0, B0]} = {d,[{{1,c},{2,g}},{{3,f},{4,f}}]},
```

and that you want to get `A` and `B` as lists (you can't have `a` and `b` as variables in Erlang):

```
A1 = tuple_to_list(A0), %% [{1,c},{2,g}],
A = lists:map(fun tuple_to_list/1, A1),
%% similarly for B
```